# Use RSelenium to perform drag-and-drop action

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I would like to use RSelenium to download files (by clicking on the excel image) from this website http://highereducationstatistics.education.gov.au/. However, before downloading the file, a series of drag-and-drop actions (see this image http://highereducationstatistics.education.gov.au/images/preDragDimension.png) have to be performed so the right dataset could be chosen (See this http://highereducationstatistics.education.gov.au/GettingStarted.aspx for instruction).

I am wondering whether RSelenium has this type of drag and drop functions. I have searched this whole day and guess that mouseMoveToLocation combined with other functions like buttondown function might be the answers, but have no idea how to use them. Can anyone help with this?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First navigate with RSelenium to the page using:

```
library(RSelenium)
rD <- rsDriver() # runs a chrome browser, wait for necessary files to download
remDr <- rD$client
remDr$navigate("http://highereducationstatistics.education.gov.au/")
```

Then locate the element you want to drag to the chart/grid. In this example I will be selecting the Course Level from the left menu.

```
webElem1 <- remDr$findElement('xpath', "//span[@title = 'Course Level']")
```

Select the element where you want to drop this menu item. In this case the element has an `id = "olapClientGridXrowHeader"`:

```
webElem2 <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id', "olapClientGridXrowHeader")
```

Once both items are selected, drag the first one into the second one like this:

```
remDr$mouseMoveToLocation(webElement = webElem1)
remDr$buttondown()
remDr$mouseMoveToLocation(webElement = webElem2)
remDr$buttonup()
```

Notice that these methods work on the remote driver, not the elements.